# Android Repo Sync Error

Tags: linux, git, android, source-control

Hi I am trying to clone lineage os 18.1 but when a do a repo sync it gives me this error.

```
Fetching:  0% (0/857) warming uperror: Cannot fetch LineageOS/android (Error: [('/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/project-objects/LineageOS/android.git/branches', '/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/projects/android.git/branches', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/projects/android.git/branches'")])
error: Cannot fetch LineageOS/android_build_blueprint (Error: [('/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/project-objects/LineageOS/android_build_blueprint.git/branches', '/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/projects/build/blueprint.git/branches', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/projects/build/blueprint.git/branches'")])
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 343, in _FetchProjectList
    return [self._FetchOne(opt, x) for x in projects]
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 343, in <listcomp>
    return [self._FetchOne(opt, x) for x in projects]
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 372, in _FetchOne
    partial_clone_exclude=self.manifest.PartialCloneExclude)
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1115, in Sync_NetworkHalf
    self._InitGitDir(force_sync=force_sync, quiet=quiet)
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2481, in _InitGitDir
    copy_all=True)
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2735, in _ReferenceGitDir
    shutil.copytree(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 365, in copytree
    raise Error(errors)
shutil.Error: [('/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/project-objects/LineageOS/android.git/branches', '/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/projects/android.git/branches', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/projects/android.git/branches'")]
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/main.py", line 651, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/main.py", line 627, in _Main
    result = run()
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/main.py", line 620, in <lambda>
    run = lambda: repo._Run(name, gopts, argv) or 0
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/main.py", line 286, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 1032, in Execute
    ssh_proxy)
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 499, in _FetchMain
    success, fetched = self._Fetch(to_fetch, opt, err_event, ssh_proxy)
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 457, in _Fetch
    if not _ProcessResults(results):
  File "/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 410, in _ProcessResults
    for results in results_sets:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 347, in <genexpr>
    return (item for chunk in result for item in chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 735, in next
    raise value
shutil.Error: [('/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/project-objects/LineageOS/android.git/branches', '/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/projects/android.git/branches', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/x/android/lineage/18.1/.repo/projects/android.git/branches'")]
```

I am using ubuntu terminal on windows using wsl.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: repo sync is not working on my pc it throws this error.